# How to name json data modification function

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

I have a data that is in json format. I need to keep it in json, but reorder it little for me to send it to the client. What name should I give to the function that does this reordering? Would *serializeSomething* be a good name? I have learned that serialization is the process of converting data to a form which can be more easily transferred over network. Well, now I already have it in JSON form, but I just need to shake it a little. Would it be correct to call that a serialization function? Or perhaps some other name would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds more like a transformation than serialization.  Serialization always starts from an object model and transforms that into something like JSON, XML, or binary protocol used to represent hierarchal data.  But it just depends on what you are doing to the data.  We don't have any details about that.

We don't even understand how you are accepting your data.  You say you have it in JSON form, but what does that mean exactly?  Is it a JSON string?  It is JSON objects?  What language are you working in?  The only indication is the tag you added: javascript.  Is that in the browser or the server?  I infer it might be on the server, but it's not clear.

Comment: Agreed, OP appears to modify the data but preserve the format, both of which would be the opposite of what you'd expect from a serialization method.

Comment: It's NodeJS, server side. It is JSON objects.

Comment: I'm not changing the data. Just transferring it to a format that is more friendly to the client. This involves creating json objects from multiple objects that are logically related to each other, but in the raw data, they are separate objects.

Comment: "JSON objects" in Javascript are just basically Javascript objects.  They aren't really anything special like in other languages.  So this is really just transformation of an yourTransformation(objectModel) -> transformedModel -> JSON(transformedModel) -> JSON.

Comment: This my least liked pattern in software development using the dreaded parallel object hierarchies.  You have one object model for the server and another for the client.  You end up created a lot of work for yourself and maintaining your program when you do this.  Also you've eliminated any real benefit of using serialization since you're writing transformations by hand between your two models.

Comment: We actually get the data from a third party. Though still you are correct, we are using (currently) a bit different format for the end backend. Though we hopefully change that in the future

Comment: Also, the system where we are getting the data will shut down soon, so no worries for a long maintenance over this.

Comment: Well 3rd party object models are excluded then since you don't maintain those. :-)  Parallel objects models can't be avoided, but really it's not exactly a parallel model then if someone else maintains it...even for a little while. ;-)